# How can I toggle only the element which was clicked? And why is 'clicking' not firing?

Tags: javascript, toggleswitch

Toggles apply to all elements with this named class. How can I change this to only the element that I clicked on?

```
<input type="file" id="file-input" multiple>
<div id="file-list">
</div>

$('#file-input').change(function(e) {
  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsBinaryString(f);
      ....

      reader.onload = function(e) {
         var label1, text1="Text1", labelEdit;
         label1 = '<span class="editable">' + text1 + '</span> + 
                  '<input class="editable" type="text" style="display:none">'
         labelEdit = "<a class="edit">Edit</a> 

         $('file-list').append(label1, labelEdit);             

     }
   }
}

$('.edit').click(function() {
     $(this).closest('.editable').toggle();
     alert('clicked');
});
```

I am trying to toggle the label and the input before 'Edit' link. Somehow the click is not firing up. What am I missing?

Comment: provide a working example to illustrate your issue

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap every label and input into some tag, say `span`, and then use click event to get the target element you have clicked, then using this target you can get the previous sibling with JQuery `prev()` method and toggle it.

In code it may look like this:

```
// your code here
label1 = '<span><span class="editable">' + text1 + '</span> + 
         '<input class="editable" type="text" style="display:none"></span>';
labelEdit = "<a class="edit">Edit</a>"; 
// some code again
```

then like this

```
$('.edit').click(function (e) {
    $(e.target).prev().toggle();
});
```